# Finding average value in list of dictionaries based on another unique value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that have an "index" and a "weight" value. I want to average the dictionaries based on any unique index. So, with the below example, how can I find the average weight for any given index (e.g. 0, 1, 250, etc.)? There will be 8 total elements for each index.

```py
values = [
{'index': 0, 'weight': 0.5},
{'index': 1, 'weight': 0.5},
{'index': 0, 'weight': 0.5},
{'index': 1, 'weight': 0.5},
{'index': 0, 'weight': 0.0},
{'index': 1, 'weight': 1.0},
{'index': 0, 'weight': 0.0},
{'index': 1, 'weight': 1.0},
{'index': 0, 'weight': 0.0},
{'index': 1, 'weight': 1.0},
{'index': 0, 'weight': 1.0},
{'index': 1, 'weight': 0.0},
{'index': 0, 'weight': 1.0},
{'index': 1, 'weight': 0.0},
{'index': 0, 'weight': 1.0},
{'index': 1, 'weight': 0.0}
]
```

I know I can get the average weight for the whole list using the following code, but I'm not sure how to do this per unique index:

```py
print(sum(v['weight'] for v in values ) / len(values))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group weights by index. defaultdict from the built-in collections module is useful here.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
total = defaultdict(int)
cnts = defaultdict(int)
for d in values:
    # add weights
    total[d['index']] += d['weight']
    # count indexes
    cnts[d['index']] += 1
# find the mean
[{'index': k, 'mean weight': total[k]/cnts[k]} for k in total]
# [{'index': 0, 'mean weight': 0.5}, {'index': 1, 'mean weight': 0.5}]
```

Comment: This appears to be the best answer for the `index` being unknown before running the code. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `pandas` for this task. Simply create your dataframe by passing your list of dictionary objects to the `DataFrame()` constructor and then perform a `groupby()` and `mean()` calculation:

```
avgs = pd.DataFrame(values).groupby('index').mean()
```

Yields:

```
       weight
index
0         0.5
1         0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only Python

```
def compute_avg(l, index):
    count = 0
    value = 0
    for data in l:
        if data['index'] == index:
            count += 1
            value += data['weight']

    return value/count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the values with your given index like this:

```
with_index = [v for v in values if v['index'] == given_index]
```

Then call this to show the average weight.

```
print(sum(v['weight'] for v in with_index ) / len(values))
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the values and track in real time:

```
x = {}
for v in values:
    try:
        x[v['index']]['weight'] += v['weight']
    except KeyError:
        x[v['index']] = {'weight' : v['weight']}
    try:
        x[v['index']]['count'] += 1
    except KeyError:
        x[v['index']].update({'count':1})

    #or wait until after the loop to calculate
    #allows for continuation in a streaming situation. 

    avg = x[v['index']]['weight'] / x[v['index']]['count']
    x[v['index']].update({'avg': avg})
    
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use Mean from the pure Python Statistics library

We can use [statistics.mean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) to solve the problem:

```py
from statistics import mean

average_weight = {
    index: mean(v['weight'] for v in values if v['index'] == index) 
    for index in set(v['index'] for v in values)
}
```

On test values

```
values = [
    {'index': 0, 'weight': 0.5},
    {'index': 1, 'weight': 0.5},
    {'index': 0, 'weight': 0.5},
    {'index': 1, 'weight': 0.5},
    {'index': 0, 'weight': 0.0},
    {'index': 1, 'weight': 1.0},
    {'index': 0, 'weight': 0.0},
    {'index': 1, 'weight': 1.0},
    {'index': 0, 'weight': 0.0},
    {'index': 1, 'weight': 1.0},
    {'index': 0, 'weight': 1.0},
    {'index': 1, 'weight': 0.0},
    {'index': 0, 'weight': 1.0},
    {'index': 1, 'weight': 0.0},
    {'index': 0, 'weight': 1.0},
    {'index': 1, 'weight': 0.0}
]
```

the `average_weight` is

```py
{0: 0.5, 1: 0.5}
```

### Use known info

If you know that *there will be 8 total elements for each index*, why not to use it?

```
COUNT = 8

average_weight = {
    index: sum(v['weight'] for v in values if v['index'] == index) / COUNT
    for index in set(v['index'] for v in values)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
indexes = set([v['index'] for v in values])
for i in indexes:
  print(sum(v['weight'] for v in values if v['index'] == i ) / sum([v['index'] == i for v in values]))
```

This is a variation of your code. It uses type conversion to count the number of dictionaries with each index.